# Syntax error in Cocoapods podfile

Tags: xcode, swift3, cocoapods

When I run the "pod install" command in the Terminal, I get this error message:

```
[!] Invalid `Podfile` file: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '('.

 #  from /Users/pdenlinger/Desktop/Clima-master/Podfile:1
 #  -------------------------------------------
 >  Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
 #  platform :ios, '9.0'
 #  -------------------------------------------
```

Here are the contents of the podfile, which I edited with Xcode:

```
Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'Clima' do
# Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
use_frameworks!

# Pods for Clima

    pod 'SwiftyJSON'
    pod 'Alamofire'
    pod 'SVProgressHUD'

end
```

Answer (score 4):

Comment the first line:

```
#Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
```

Not a great error message ...